# Is there a way to exclude some functions from custom iOS framework headers automatically?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am working on an iOS framework and i want to have ability to exclude some methods from headers in compile time. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understood. Is marking the method `private` what you want?

Comment: No. I want to trim some methods from header file in build time with condition.

Answer (score 0):

l think l've found a solution. unifdef in build settings.